# How to compare value from table in call back function in codeigniter form validaiton

Tags: codeigniter

This is my Callback function for form validation in CodeIgniter

```
public function user_check($str)
{
    if ($str == 'sounitkar13')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('user_check', 'The %s is not found in our record');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

right now i am comparing $str with "sounitkar13" but i have a table with 100 username stored so i want to compare with those 100 user names and if it matches with any of those 100 then return TRUE otherwise FALSE.  ( it is reverse of is_unique function.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do condition on table rows using where condition

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array(
            'username' => $str
        ));

$count = $query->num_rows();

if ($Count != 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('user_check', 'The %s is not found in our record');
        return FALSE;
    }
```